# C# Object and class in XNA

Tags: c#, class, object, xna

I am creating a class with specific number of objects.When these objects are created and drawn on screen with that capacity again I reinitialize that class.The problem is that I want to reinitialize in such a way that if new objects are created then previous must be persist/drawn on the screen.I am not able to get the logic.

```
crShade = new CreateShade[Obj_num]; for (int i = incr_Obj; i < crShade.Length; i++) {
    int r = rad.Next(0, 7); int x = 0; switch (r) {
        case 0: x = 0; break; case 1: x = 120; break; case 2: x = 240; break; case 3: x = 360; break;
    }
    X_pos.Add(x); crShade[i] = new CreateShade(x, -60, clr[3]); _Shade.Add(crShade[i]);
}
```

--

```
public class CreateShade {
    public int posX; public int posY; public Color color; Random r = new Random(); private int width = 120; private int height = 60; public static bool _Fall; public static bool check; public static List<int> y_pos = new List<int>(); int balance = 0; public CreateShade(int x, int y, Color color) {
        int random = r.Next(0, 4); this.posY = y; this.posX = x; this.color = color;
    }
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
        batch.Draw(Vimap_ScreenManager.blank, new Rectangle(posX, posY, width, height), color);
    }
    public void update() {
        int counter = 0; if (posY != 740-balance) {
            posY += 10; if (counter != y_pos.Count) {
                if (new Rectangle(posX, posY, 120, 60).Intersects(new Rectangle(VimapGamePage.X_pos.ElementAt(counter), y_pos.ElementAt(counter), 120, 60))) {
                    balance = counter * 60;
                }
                else {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            //check = true;
        }
        else {
            y_pos.Add(posY); _Fall = true; // VimapGamePage.End_Reach = true;
        }
    }
    public void Move_X(Point p) {
        if (p.X <= 240) {
            if (p.X >= 0 && p.X <= 120) {
                posX = 0;
            }
            else if (p.X > 120 && p.X <= 240) {
                posX = 120;
            }
        }
        else if (p.X > 240) {
            if (p.X > 240 && p.X <= 360) {
                posX = 240;
            }
            else if (p.X > 360 && p.X <= 480) {
                posX = 360;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add  your code to the question.

Comment: You can use separate classes for store your object and initialize them.

Comment: As it is, without any code; it is really difficult to understand the problem you are facing and possible solutions. Please update your question by adding the relevant pieces of code so that we may help you.

Comment: Actually I am working on a game in XNA .In this game colored bar fall from top of the screen and player has to form a full image. I am dong with the help of class and objects.It is then require to create "How many object?".Rather I want to create single object but reinitialize that .

Comment: the portion of code in Initialize is following.....
crShade = new CreateShade[Obj_num];
            for (int i = incr_Obj; i < crShade.Length; i++)
            {
                int r = rad.Next(0, 7);
                int x = 0;

Comment: switch (r)
                {
                    case 0:
                        x = 0;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        x = 120;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        x = 240;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        x = 360;
                        break;
                }
                X_pos.Add(x);
                crShade[i] = new CreateShade(x, -60, clr[3]);
                _Shade.Add(crShade[i]);

            }

Comment: the class used is...

Comment: public class CreateShade
    {
        public int posX;
        public int posY;
        public Color color;
        Random r = new Random();
        private int width = 120;
        private int height = 60;
        public static bool _Fall;
        public static bool check;
        public static List<int> y_pos = new List<int>();
        int balance = 0;
        public CreateShade(int x, int y, Color color)
        {
            int random = r.Next(0, 4);

            this.posY = y;
            this.posX = x;
            this.color = color;
        }

Comment: public void draw(SpriteBatch batch)
        {
            batch.Draw(Vimap_ScreenManager.blank, new Rectangle(posX, posY, width, height), color);
        }

        public void update()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            if (posY != 740-balance)
            {
                posY += 10;

Comment: if (counter != y_pos.Count)
                {
                    if (new Rectangle(posX, posY, 120, 60).Intersects(new Rectangle(VimapGamePage.X_pos.ElementAt(counter), y_pos.ElementAt(counter), 120, 60)))
                    {
                        balance = counter * 60;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                //check = true;
            }

Comment: else
            {
                y_pos.Add(posY);
                _Fall = true;
                // VimapGamePage.End_Reach = true;
            }
        }
        public void Move_X(Point p)
        {
            if (p.X <= 240)
            {
                if (p.X >= 0 && p.X <= 120)
                {
                    posX = 0;
                }
                else if (p.X > 120 && p.X <= 240)
                {
                    posX = 120;
                }
            }

Comment: else if (p.X > 240)
            {
                if (p.X > 240 && p.X <= 360)
                {
                    posX = 240;
                }
                else if (p.X > 360 && p.X <= 480)
                {
                    posX = 360;
                }

            }
        }
    }

Comment: @SiddharthMishra, next time, please add your code to the post by clicking the edit button.